# XSLT - Put Javascript at the end of the DOM

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, dom

I have some JavaScript codes which are currently printed directly in the DOM.

Like that:

```
    <div id="a" class="widget"></div>
    <script>$('#a').animate()</script>
    <div id="b" class="widget"></div>
    <script>$('#b').animate()</script>
</body>
```

I would like to put all that JavaScript parts at the end of the DOM without changing all my XSL/JavaScript too much. Is it possible?

```
    <div id="a" class="widget"></div>
    <div id="b" class="widget"></div>
    <script>$('#a').animate()</script>
    <script>$('#b').animate()</script>
</body>
```

My first try was to use a Java String Object and pass it to all my templates.

```
<xsl:variable name="footerPlaceholder" select="String:new()"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="item">
  <xsl:with-param name="footerPlaceholder" select="$footerPlaceholder" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
<xsl:value-of select="String:toString($footerPlaceholder)"/>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:param name="footerPlaceholder" />
  <xsl:value-of select="String:concat($footerPlaceholder, 'test')"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="String:toString($footerPlaceholder)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This does not seems to work. The final `toString` is always empty and the `toString` within the template only contains one `test`.

EDIT:

I add a basic example here. Obviously it's pretty simple so I could for example create two template for the widget. One render and one javascript. I can't do it in the real app, this would be too much work.

XML

```
<root>
<widget id="a"></widget>
<widget id="b"></widget>
</root>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./widget" mode="render" />
        </body>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="widget" mode="render">
        <div id="{@id}" class="widget"></div>
        <script>$('#<xsl:value-of select="@id" />').animate()</script>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Final solution (Thanks Martin)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <body>
      <xsl:variable name="body">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./widget" mode="render" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$body" mode="no-script" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="$body//script" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>
    </body>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="script" mode="no-script">
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(self::script)] | @*" mode="no-script">
    <xsl:copy  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::script)] | @*"  mode="no-script"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="widget" mode="render">
    <div id="{@id}" class="widget"></div>
    <div>
      <script>$('#<xsl:value-of select="@id" />').animate()</script>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If the first snippet is created by XSLT and that XSLT does not literally output the sequence you have shown there but involves different templates or processing then to enable us to answer the question you need to show the XML input and the XSLT, both minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added a very simple example.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use a second mode to output the `script` elements and then do `<body><xsl:apply-templates select="./widget" mode="render" /><xsl:apply-templates select="./widget" mode="script" /></body>`. But your statement indicates you don't want to go that route. I don't understand your other approach using Java so can't comment on that.

Comment: Yes there are too much templates, I don't want to rebuild everything. My idea with using Java String was to have a sort of container where I put all the javascript code and it will be output at the end of the main template. Unfortunately the string is empty in the template of the widget.

Comment: I posted an answer which should with XSLT 2.0 in pure XSLT without relying on any Java/XSLT interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 2.0 use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <body>
            <xsl:variable name="widgets">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./widget" mode="render" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$widgets/div, $widgets/script"/>
        </body>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="widget" mode="render">
        <div id="{@id}" class="widget"></div>
        <script>$('#<xsl:value-of select="@id" />').animate()</script>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great I think I could work for me, Thanks! Do you know why is `<body/>` empty when I add this line `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` to the `<xsl:stylesheet>` ?

Comment: @Charles, if you put the result elements in a namespace then `<xsl:copy-of select="$widgets/div, $widgets/script"/>` does not select them as it selects `div` or `script` elements in no namespace. You can of course fix that doing `<xsl:copy-of select="$widgets/div, $widgets/script" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>`

Comment: `xpath-default-namespace` did the trick this is great, Thanks again! I added my final solution to the question, I hope it will help.